# Command find unix ,linux

Tags: linux, unix, sh

we write a command that takes a number n through stdin. The command must write the number to the standard output obtained by writing the numbers 1,2,3....,n in succession, alternating the -(subtraction) and +(addition) operators between any two consecutive digits, and calculate the expression thus obtained. For n = 12 we get for example:
1-2+3-4+5-6+7-8+9-1+0-1+1-1+2 = 5

```
$ echo 12 | ...
5
$ echo 82 | ...
 14
```

we need to change (...) with a code to get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. I'm using busybox `awk` to accomplish this task.

***Example 1:***

```sh
echo 12 | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=$0;++i) { len=split(i,nums,""); for(j=1;j<=len;++j) arr[++n]=nums[j] }} END { for(i=1;i<=n;++i) if(i%2==0) { r-=arr[i]} else { r+=arr[i] } print r }'
```

Output:

```sh
5
```

***Example 2:***

```sh
echo 82 | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=$0;++i) { len=split(i,nums,""); for(j=1;j<=len;++j) arr[++n]=nums[j] }} END { for(i=1;i<=n;++i) if(i%2==0) { r-=arr[i]} else { r+=arr[i] } print r }'
```

Output:

```sh
19
```